# How can I simultaneously restrict complete sitewide access by IP Address whilst providing limited access to `wp-admin` by IP Address?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to block several IP Addresses from accessing all pages on a website I am working on.  As well as this, I would like to limit access to the `wp-admin` folder to only a handful of IP Addresses.

**Root Level `.htaccess` File**

I have created the above file and entered the following code:

```
# Restrict Access to the following IP Addresses.
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from **.***.*.**
deny from ***.***.**.***
deny from **.***.*.*
</Files>
```

**`wp-admin` Directory Level `.htaccess` File**

Now that I have limited sitewide access to the desired IP Addresses, I would like to restrict all access to the `wp-admin` folder, only allowing a handful of IP Addresses access.  To achieve this, I entered the following code into the relevant `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "WordPress Admin Access Control"
AuthType Basic
<LIMIT GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
# IP Address A:
allow from ***.***.***.***
# IP Address B:
allow from **.***.***.***
# IP Address C:
allow from **.**.**.**
</LIMIT>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get this work. It appears that the Server/Website will only allow for one set of coding to work.  In other words, I can either restrict access at Root Level or at `wp-admin` Directory.

If I have both files uploaded, it seems that the Root level `.htaccess` file takes priority as when I remove the relevant coding (but leave the file uploaded), the `wp-admin` `.htaccess` starts working.

Is it a case that files, at Root Level, take priority?

Any ideas on how this be resolved?

**Edit | Rewrite Engine:**

I currently have the following code, within the Root level `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I placed the above code, within the Directory level `.htaccess`, would this resolve the issue or cause other issues instead?

Comment: " it seems that the Root level .htaccess file takes priority as when I remove the relevant coding " - Yes that's true .Your web server is unable to find the `/Folder/.htaccess` because you are not using  `RewriteEngine On` in your directory  level .htaccess .

Comment: I have just updated the question with the current `RewriteEngine`, entry I have.  Is this what is missing from the directory level `.htaccess` file?